# offizielles amtliches Grammatik-Regelwerk

Tags: rules

Bis 1996 war in Deutschland der Duden das offizielle Nachschlagewerk für die Rechtschreibung von deutschen Wörtern. Seit 1996 gibt der *Rat der deutschen Rechtschreibung* das amtliche Regelwerk der deutschen Rechtschreibung heraus, und das Österreichische Wörterbuch, das ebenfalls ein amtliches Rechtschreib-Regelwerk ist, folgt dem Regelwerk dieses Rates, denn österreichisches Deutsch und deutsches Deutsch stimmen in der Rechtschreibung (bis auf sehr wenige vernachlässigbare Unterschiede) exakt überein.

Aber das alles betrifft nur die Rechtschreibung. Also die Art und Weise, wie bereits vorhandene Texte in die Schriftform zu gießen sind. (»*Bereits vorhanden*« im Sinn von: »*Im Kopf des Autors bereits ausformuliert*«.) Diese amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln betreffen ausschließlich die geschriebene Sprache, sie haben absolut keinen Einfluss auf die gesprochene Sprache.

Es gibt aber auch Regeln, die festlegen, wie Wörter zu Sätzen zusammenzufügen sind, damit sie als sinntragende Einheiten weitergegeben und vom Empfänger verstanden werden können. Dieses Teilgebiet der Sprache ist die Grammatik, und sie betrifft gesprochene und geschriebene Sprache gleichermaßen. Grammatik behandelt die Beziehungen zwischen Wörtern in einem Satz, und in einigen Fällen auch über den Satz hinaus.

Ich gehe davon aus, dass es auch dafür ein offizielles Regelwerk gibt. Wenn ich im Internet nach Grammatikregeln suche, finde ich viele Webseiten, die sich diesem Thema widmen, und die das meiner Einschätzung nach oft auch ganz hervorragend machen. Aber auf keiner dieser Seiten fand ich einen Hinweis darauf, dass diese spezielle Seite von einer offiziellen und amtlichen Stelle betrieben wird. Ich fand bisher auch nirgendwo einen Verweis auf eine solche amtliche Stelle.

Daher meine Fragen:

- Gibt es überhaupt ein amtliches Regelwerk der deutschen Grammatik?
- Wenn ja: Wer gibt dieses amtliche Grammatik-Regelwerk heraus?

---

### Nachtrag:

Ich formuliere die Frage anhand eines Beispiels neu:

Ein Schüler schreibt in einem Aufsatz:

> In unserer Garage steht dem Vater sein Auto.

Der Lehrer sieht darin einen Fehler, korrigiert den Satz zu

> In unserer Garage steht das Auto meines Vaters.

und gibt dem Schüler deswegen eine schlechte Note. Wenige Tage später kommt *dem Schüler sein Vater* in *dem Lehrer seine Sprechstunde* und diskutiert mit dem Lehrer. Der Vater behauptet, *seinem Sohn sein Satz* wäre völlig korrekt, der Lehrer behauptet das Gegenteil.
(Kursiv gesetzte Satzteile sind absichtlich in einer alternativen Grammatik verfasst, die vielerorts aber die tatsächlich vorherrschende Grammatik der alltäglichen Umgangssprache ist.)

**Worauf kann sich der Lehrer bei seiner Argumentation berufen?**

---

### zweiter Nachtrag

Anders Beispiel, nämlich der eigentliche Grund für meine Frage:

Die [Wiener Zeitung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_Zeitung) (gegründet 1703) ist nicht nur eine der ältesten Tageszeitungen der Welt, sonder auch eine mit sehr hohem journalistischem und sprachlichem Niveau. Vor drei Tagen erschien darin der Artikel [Zu viel Licht über Wien](http://www.wienerzeitung.at/nachrichten/wien/stadtleben/874354_Zu-viel-Licht-ueber-Wien.html). Ein Satz dieses Artikels löste auf Facebook eine Diskussion aus, jedoch nicht wegen seines Inhalts, sondern wegen eines vermeintlichen Grammatikfehlers. Der Satz lautet:

> Die Kuffner-Sternwarte will sich gemeinsam mit der Vogelschutzorganisation Birdlife Österreich und dem Umweltdachverband nun den anderen beiden Dritteln annehmen.

<sub>(Zum Verständnis: Laut Artikel geht die Lichtverschmutzung zu je einem Drittel auf das Konto der öffentlichen Straßenbeleuchtung, der Geschäftsbeleuchtung und der privaten Beleuchtung von Fassaden. Die Stadt Wien kümmert sich bereits um eines dieser Drittel, nämlich um die Straßenbeleuchtung. Die beiden anderen Drittel sind Inhalt des zitierten Satzes.)</sub>

Kritisiert wurde, dass eine so renommierte Qualitätszeitung wie die Wiener Zeitung den Dativ verwendet, wo nach Meinung einiger Kommentatoren zwingend und alternativlos der Genitiv erforderlich gewesen wäre. Es wurde empört geschimpft, es müsse doch wie folgt lauten:

> Die Kuffner-Sternwarte will sich [...] <del>*den*</del> **der** anderen beiden <del>*Dritteln*</del> **Drittel** annehmen.

Dabei haben die Genitiv-Verfechter die Dativ-Anhänger natürlich auch sofort mit dem Duden verprügelt.

Ich habe daraufhin recherchiert, und bin auf eine Seite gestoßen, die sich mit [Grammatikfragen](http://www.grammatikfragen.de/showthread.php?132-Sich-der-G%E4ste-annehmen-oder-sich-den-G%E4sten-annehmen) beschäftigt. Dort ist zu lesen:

> Obwohl der Gebrauch von *annehmen* mit Dativ standardsprachlich nicht anerkannt ist, scheint er im Sprachgebrauch durchaus weit verbreitet zu sein. Eine Google-Suche zu "nehmen sich des Problems/dem Problem an" ergab 830 Treffer für die Variante mit Genitiv und 1030 Treffer für die Variante mit Dativ.

Diese Suche wurde im August 2011 gemacht. Ich habe diese Suche heute (19.2.2017) wiederholt, und finde:

- Genitiv "nehmen sich des Problems an": Ungefähr 746 Ergebnisse
- Dativ "nehmen sich dem Problem an": Ungefähr 1880 Ergebnisse

Das bedeutet dann aber, dass 72% aller Menschen (2011 waren es noch 55%) *sich annehmen* nicht mit dem Genitiv, sondern mit dem Dativ verwenden.

Da stellt sich für mich einerseits die Frage, wer den Herausgebern von Grammatikbüchern das Recht gibt, zu behaupten, eine Variante, die von drei Viertel der Bevölkerung verwendet wird, wäre falsch.

**Andererseits würde ich aber auch gerne wissen, wer denn überhaupt die oberste Instanz bei solchen Streitfällen ist, und genau darum geht es in meiner Frage.**

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass es so etwas offizielles gibt. Gerade die Sprache ist etwas, das niemand besitzen kann und das ist auch gut so. Man kann Gesellschaften oder Räte formen, die einem Regeln oder viel mehr Leit- statt Richtlinien vorgeben. Man kann Beobachtungen treffen und zusammen tragen. Doch Sprache unterliegt einer ständigen (Weiter-)Entwicklung bzw. Wandel. Solche Vorgaben werden bzw. wurden gemacht, damit man sich unmissverständlich miteinander austauschen kann. Daher würde ich sagen, dass deine gefundenen Webseiten das beste Orientierungsmittel ist.

Comment: Warum soll es eine "offizielle" Grammatik geben? Das gibt es ja in anderen Sprachen auch nicht; mehr oder weniger renommierte Verlage fassen diese Regeln dann zusammen, und die Benutzer können sich daran orientieren.

Comment: „Grammatik … betrifft gesprochene und geschriebene Sprache gleichermaßen“ Jein. Es gibt zwar medial mündliche Sprache, die konzeptionell schriftlich ist, und andersrum, aber im Allgemeinen unterscheiden sich die Grammatik der Schriftsprache und der Umgangssprache signifikant voneinander. Die meisten Grammatikbücher/-webseiten behandeln nur Regularitäten der geschriebenen Sprache, obwohl sie mitunter anderes behaupten.

Comment: @Crissov: Dass sich die Grammatiken von mündlicher und schriftlicher Sprache voneinander unterscheiden, steht außer Zweifel. Ich habe nichts gegenteiliges behauptet, sondern nur festgestellt, dass Grammatik im Gegensatz zur Rechtschreibung nicht nur geschriebene, sondern auch gesprochene Sprache betrifft. Mir würde aber ohnehin bereits ein amtliches Grammatik-Regelwerk für geschriebenes Deutsch reichen.

Comment: Der Lehrer kann sich darauf berufen, dass er dem Schüler das anders beigebracht hat. Das ist auch in anderen Fächern der Maßstab der Bewertung. In den Naturwissenschaften zählt auch der Lehrplan und nicht der Stand der Forschung.

Comment: Dabei wird dann aber in aller Regel auf den Duden verwiesen. Warum gerade der Duden ist hoffentlich eindeutig ansonsten erläutere ich es kurz. Allerdings ist das Konzept "Schule" meines Erachtens nach (freundlich ausgedrückt) nicht sehr gut. Es muss unbedingt etwas getan werden aber ich will hier keine Diskussion anstoßen. Dennoch wenn es hieß es gäbe nun weitere Elemente im Periodensystem dann wurden diese auch anerkannt auch wenn der Lehrplan etwas anderes sagen würde.

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel: Der Verweis auf den Duden erscheint mir nicht schlüssig. Das ist ein Buch, das vom Brockhaus-Verlag herausgegeben wird. Dieser Verlag ist eine Aktiengesellschaft, also nicht in öffentlicher Hand. Was ist am Duden anderes als an allen anderen ähnlichen Nachschlagewerken, z.B. canoo.net? Was gilt, wenn sich diese Nachschlagwerke widersprechen?

Comment: Noch einmal: es gibt hier kein offizielles Regulatorium, ist ja kein Gesetz. Diverse Fachverlage geben ihre Wörterbücher und Grammatiken heraus an die man sich halten kann -- aber nicht muss. Ein Verstoß dagegen kennt keine direkten Sanktionen (außer dass sich vielleicht manche Leser ihren Teil denken werden, oder die Verwendung für falsch halten.) Der Sprachgebrauch ist dabei auch einem stetigen Wandel ausgesetzt, und die Verlage haben sich vom Präskriptivismus schon lange verabschiedet: sie schauen dem Volk vielmehr nur mehr "aufs Maul", und schreiben nieder, was sie sehen (Deskriptivismus).

Comment: @Ingmar: "keine direkten Sanktionen" stimmt nicht. Wenn ein Schüler bei einer Abschlussprüfung eine schlechtere Note bekommt, weil er "Er nahm sich **dem Problem** an" geschrieben hat, dann kann das im Extremfall den Ausschlag darüber geben, ob er einen Studienplatz an einer Uni bekommt. Und das ist eine wesentlich weitreichendere Weichenstellung für das Leben eines Menschen als die Zahlung eines Bußgeldes für Falschparken.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt keine oberste Instanz in Fragen der Grammatik.

Comment: Und zwar in kaum einer Sprache (ausgenommen, vielleicht, die Académie française?), ganz sicher nicht in Deutsch oder Englisch.